# How to display block inline?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a page where I have to divide the description boxes(named block2 here) into four groups and display 2 of them on each line. I added `display:inline;` tag to block2 but still each of the block is being displayed on a new line. I will be very thankful if anyone could help me out. Thanks
Here is my code,

```
.block2{
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    background-color:#ECECEC;
    padding:17px 13px 21px 22px;
    margin:6px 6px 0 0;
    color:#636363
}
.block2 p{
    width:462px; 
    height:400px;  <!-- Height of the box containing details(one for all) -->
    float:left;
    padding:19px 0 13px 16px;
}
.block2 p img{
float:left;
margin:0 10px 7px 0
}
```

And below is its HTML,

```
        <div class="block2">

                Provide here the details about first member 

        </div>

    <div class="block2">

            Member 2's details
        </div>

<div class="block2">



            Member 3's details

    </div>

<div class="block2">

            Member 4's details

    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your padding doesn't exceed the width of the container?

Comment: Does `display:inline-block;` not work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U5ETm/ seems to look *ok*?

Comment: @Will: Thanks. It was the issue of width overflow. Can you please provide this as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to have been a simple padding issue, where the width caused it to overflow. Glad I helped!

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the rule `display: inline-block`. There it is. But I should warn you that it can be a very touchy rule that is affected by white space in your HTML.

But if you are just trying to stop the overlap, try removing `display:inline;` from your `.block2` CSS rule.

Comment: +1 because `inline-block` is the answer. But I'll add that the other thing to be aware of is that IE7 and earlier have bugs with `inline-block`. It's easy to work around, but if you want to support IE7, its important to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `width` for `<p>` tag you can use it for `<div>`. I have set `<div>`'s `width` to `300px` because of `padding` and `margin` you have used (also the width exceeded the containers width) other wise you can set `width` to `50%` which then automatically displays two `<div>`s in a line.

```
.block2{
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    background-color:#ECECEC;
    padding:17px 13px 21px 22px;
    margin:6px 6px 0 0;
    color:#636363;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.block2 p{
    height:400px;  
    float:left;
    padding:19px 0 13px 16px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.block2 p img{
float:left;
margin:0 10px 7px 0
}
```

**Here is how I would prefer to do and I hope this helps you**.

```
.block2{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    background-color:#ECECEC;
    color:#636363;

}
.block2 p{
    height:400px;  
    float:left;
    padding:19px 0 13px 16px;
    border:1px solid red;

}
.block2 p img{
float:left;
margin:0 10px 7px 0
}
```

```
<div class="block2"><p>Provide here the details about first member </p></div>
<div class="block2"><p>Member 2's details</p></div>
<div class="block2"><p>Member 3's details</p></div>
<div class="block2"><p>Member 4's details</p></div>
```